# Include a new jar in aosp

Tags: android, android-source

I need to include a new jar to the aosp apart from the jars which are already there so that when i build my rom this jar could be used.

Can anyone can tell where to keep the jar. I have kept it in out/target/common/obj/JAVA_Libraries but it is not in the build path.

So i guess i need to make in make changed in makefile or something such that the new jar is included in the build path. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Did you figure it out by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the `setup-makefile.sh` script of your device.

Use the `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` directive.

Take a look at this file as an example: [cyanogenmod@github:android_device_htc_passion](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_passion/blob/gingerbread/setup-makefiles.sh)

-- EDIT --

Maybe you can even use the `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` in `build/target/product/core.mk`, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Point here is the `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` directive. Use it in a .mk file (see my edit).

Comment: what i see is only product_packages and product_property_overrides there is no product_copy_files.

Comment: I know it's not there. You should try to add it, or use it in your device'c .mk file. See the link